# Comparing Different Properties of a Class in a std::vector of a Class

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

*I really didn't know what's the proper title for this would be, please bear with me.*

So, imagine I have a class like:

```cpp
class data {
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;

    bool is_blue;
};
```

and then I use it to construct a vector, `std::vector<data> vdata`. What I’m interested in is to be able to compare values of the vector based on the given property of the class. For instance, I’d like to find the element with smallest `a`, or find all elements with `b > 2.0`, or `is_blue == true`.

I have a few ideas on how to achieve this, but they don’t cover all the cases that I want to. For instance, I can probably loop over elements of the `vdata`, select `a`’s and construct a `std::vector<double>` and then use `std::min_element` to get the min. Or, use `std::find` to find what I want.

Or, maybe I can use `std::transform` and a lambda and generate a vector indicating if my test passed or not, and then select from that, like:

```cpp
std::vector<bool> s;
std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(ordinals),
                   [](auto &d) -> bool { return d.b > 2.0 });
```

I also thought maybe I can use `std::sort` and basically sort my `vdata` based on what I’m interested in. I’m not even sure if this method make sense.

So, I know how to approach this in different ways, and they work but I feel I'm missing something, and it should be a better way that covers all the cases. *I'm mostly interested in some comparisons and min/max elements.* I also have a complete control over the `data` class, so, I can freely add to it, encapsulate it into another class, etc.

P.S. Please let me know if I can choose a better title for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the things you mention, you can use functions in the standard library. You'll need [`std::min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) (as you mentioned) and [`std::partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) (or [`std::stable_partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition)).

```
#include <algorithm> // min_element, partition

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const data& d) {
    return os << '{' << d.a << ',' << d.b << ',' << d.c << ',' << d.is_blue << '}';
}
//...

    std::cout << "element with smallest a\n";
    auto min_it = std::min_element(vdata.begin(), vdata.end(),
                                   [](const data& l, const data& r) { return l.a < r.a; });
    std::cout << *min_it << '\n';


    std::cout << "range with all b > 2.0\n";
    auto pivot = std::partition(vdata.begin(), vdata.end(),
                                [](const data& d) { return d.b > 2.; });
    for(auto it = vdata.begin(); it != pivot; ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << '\n';
    }


    std::cout << "range with all blue\n";
    pivot = std::partition(vdata.begin(), vdata.end(),
                           [](const data& d) { return d.is_blue; });
    for(auto it = vdata.begin(); it != pivot; ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << '\n';
    }
```

> I have a few ideas on how to achieve this, but they don’t cover all the cases that I want to.

There are different algorithms for different scenarios. You'll hardly find one that covers all the cases (except in some trivial cases where you may *get one for free* so to speak).

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your answer. This indeed solves my issue and even gives me some ideas on how to approach some other features that I was trying to implement.